# Issues running Java applets

Tags: java, windows, google-chrome, java-8, japplet

Recently I'm studying Java. I had no real troubles while building normal java files to .class and execute them, but, when I started a bit with applets I haven't been able to run anything.

Before I had started Java, as developer I had already a lot of development tools (Eclipse, Visual Studio, CodeBlocks and others). So, basically, I already had JDK but downloaded it again to get updated to 1.8.
Now, I have also JRE 8 and there are no troubles in using javac.exe and java.exe to build and execute, but, after building the .class file of applet, when I load the html page, I got an error which strongly recommends me to upgrade JRE.

[image: trouble]

Just to translate it:

Current version of Java is obsolete.

- Upgrade (recommended choice)
- Block
- Later

If I do the update, it gets me to this page http://java.com/it/download/index.jsp), but, it's the download link of JRE 1.7. As much as I know, JDK 1.8 is not beta (it's accessible a 1.9 preview) so why shall I use 1.7? Indeed, after downloading and installing, when I try to run the applet, the message above is shown again.

Is actually possible to install JRE 1.8 on Google Chrome?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved it. It wasn't easy since it wasn't a real trouble of java.

I had effectively Java 7 version 55 and Java 8 (but also 7-45 and 6). Java 8 was 64-bit while Java 7 was 32.
Google Chrome (32-bit browser) used so the last version it could use. According to Oracle, it's recommended to remove older versions of java (because of security) so I removed everything but the 8, and then switched to 64-bit browser (Chromium). I left older JDK installed for compatibility development reasons.